# Database and iOS application

Tags: ios, database, server, backend

I am new to iOS development, and I was hoping some of you can answer my questions.

1)How does iOS app interact with its database?

2)How does the app retrieve/update data in/from the server? Is it the same concept as web servers?

3)Can I use my web server as the backend server of my app?

I would be grateful if someone can provide a quick and easy example.

Comment: Training is out of scope for SO.  The goal here is to solve concrete programming problems.

Comment: 1) iOS has a library for communicating with sqlite3 directly or you can read about CoreData if you want object-oriented storage.  2) You have all levels of networking available from sockets up to HTTP request objects.  3) Yes.  4) Apple supplies lots of sample code.  Read about the concepts you need and download their examples.

Answer (score 2):

(Sigh.)

Go onto Ray Wenderlich's website, buy the iOS Apprentice tutorials, then come back here if - after learning the basics - you still have questions.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/store/ios-apprentice

There's a whole load of excellent tutorials out there, which will answer all three of your questions.

Even I have a tutorial, showing how to get data from a JSON web service into an iPhone app.

[iPhone app using web services](http://www.mikesknowledgebase.com/pages/Services/WebServices-Page6.htm)

Did you do any research, or follow any walkthroughs, before asking this Question ?